# ASP.NET, bind data to an asp.net control and show duplicate values only once

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, data-binding, web-controls

I am looking for an easy way to bind some data to an ASP.NET control.

Is there somebody who can tell me if it's possible to bind below query ouput to an ASP.NET control (repeater,...) and how?

[image]

I want to obtain below output with the control. (without second query)

[image]

Thank you

Frederik

Comment: To the output of the control is not clear.  Which control and what is the exact output.

Comment: @Hogan I'm pretty certain the database has a column that repeats, but he doesn't want that to be displayed, he wants to group on that column, but he isn't sure how to do the repeater and grouping I assume.

Comment: @Greg, indeed. Which asp.net control doesn't really matter. Just want to obtain above output.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to build a proper model object.  Once you've created your model, you would simply do the following to your control.

```
rpExample.DataSource = dbContext.List(..);
rpExample.DataBind();
```

In essence your approach would return a collection from the database, which is associated to your repeater.  Then you would simply bind.  However, the above is quite trivial your real problem will be the following.

1. Building a proper model
2. Determine the proper data structure to display.

Once you've identified your requirements, most will reveal itself.  But once you have an object, you can Group By, Distinct, or use some powerful functionality from Linq to assist you.